# ! Undefined control sequence. \@thehead ...@encoding \sfdefault ln\@shortauthor \hfill \ifNRC@pagewithfile... l.104 \end{document}

Tags: includegraphics

I am writing a paper for Canadian geotechnical journal. I use nrc2 documentclass. The final pdf is a two-column paper. my figures are wide so I have to span two columns. According to nrc documentation, I should use starred figure, but it does not work! This is the error I get:

```
! Undefined control sequence. 
\@thehead ...@encoding \sfdefault ln\@shortauthor \hfill 
\ifNRC@pagewithfile... l.104 
\end{document}"
```

Any help is much appreciated. This is what I have:

```
\documentclass{nrc2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
%\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
%\RequirePackage{silence}
%\WarningFilter{GUTenberg}
\usepackage{microtype}
\hfuzz=2pt
\usepackage{subfigure}

\journalcode{cgj}

\renewcommand{\topfraction}{.95} 
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{.95} 
\renewcommand{\dbltopfraction}{.95}
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{.05}
\renewcommand{\dblfloatpagefraction}{.95}

\begin{document}

\title{AAA}



\author{A1}
\address[ad]{B}
\author{A2}
\author{A3}


\correspond{email}


\begin{abstract}
text

\keywords{A1,A2,A3}
\end{abstract}
\begin{resume}
Text
\end{resume}

\maketitle


\section{Introduction}
Text

\begin{figure*}
 \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{A.pdf}
\end{figure*}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: On my machine, I do not get these errors. Yet I do get a lot of complaints about incomplete `\ifx`, which however disappear once I comment out `\usepackage{microtype}`.

Comment: `subfigure` is deprecated and ought not be used. Are you supposed to change the layout rules like that?

Comment: Please copy the code you pasted here back into a clean `.tex` file in a clean directory and compile it. Do you get the error you reported? If not, your code cannot be used to reproduce the problem. I suspect you will not get this error, which seems to involve a short author name, whereas your example does not specify any shortened author name. This might not be the problem - the class may just copy the author to the shortened author, too, so the problem is there, but it definitely involves some kind of author name and not, say, the use of `figure*`.

Comment: I copied it into a clean directory and no error appeared. However, after adding my real text into it, the error appeared again! It seems that it can not fit the text appropriately to produce the pdf! I removed all my text, and instead, I typed " text text text ...". After I repeat "text text text" to a specific number, the error appears again!

Comment: Before adding the figure* into my draft, there was no error so I thought that the problem is within the figure*. But, now, it seems that the problem is related to the combination of having a spanning figure and a lot of text in abstract and introduction. By the way, I don't need subfigure package so one can remove that from the code.

Comment: This is another error that is appeared in blue colour: LaTeX Warning: Float too large for page by 17.81725pt on input line 289.

Comment: That latest message is a *warning message*, not an *error message*. It's telling you that the vertical height of the float exceeds the `\textheigtht` parameter by 17.8 points. Since you haven't told us much about this float, it's not possible to offer constructive advice on what you should do.

Answer (score 3):

Some comments and observations:

- The user guide of the `nrc` and `nrc2` document classes states, at the bottom of page 4, that a `\shortauthor{...}` instruction must be provided and that an error message (not a *warning message*) will be generated if no `\shortauthor` instruction is provided. In case you're curious: The argument of `\shortauthor` will appear in the document's running header.

  Observe that this error message is wholly independent of whether or not you use any `figure*` environments.
- If you don't need the obsolete and deprecated `subfigure` package, by all means don't load it. In a similar vein: Are you sure you need to reset `topfraction`, `\floatpagefraction`, `\dbltopfraction`, etc?
- I gather that the remaining issue is how to get rid of the warning message about the float being "too large for the page" by 17.82 points. Assuming that the code snippets you've posted are representative of the real document, the warning message must come from the following group of instructions:

  ```
  \begin{figure*}
   \includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{A.pdf}
  \end{figure*}
  ```

  The warning message says that the total height of the float currently exceeds the height of the text block by 17.82 points. The height of the text block is governed by the parameter `\textheight`. To make the warning message go away, you could either increase the value of `\textheight` -- not recommended, because that parameter is set by the document class, and because it's probably not a good idea to fiddle with its parameter settings -- or you could reduce the vertical dimension of the included pdf file. To implement the second option while not introducing any new distotions, you should replace the three lines shown above with

  ```
  \begin{figure*}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,
                    height=\textheight,
                    keepaspectratio]{A.pdf}
  \end{figure*}
  ```

  The `keepaspectratio` option directs LaTeX to adjust (here: *reduce*) the width of the graphic so that the graph's height will be equal to `\textheight`. The `\centering` instruction performs horizontal centering.